# SBT one-jar plugin

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using sbt 0.11.3 (also tried on 0.11.2), and scala 2.9.1.Final.

I have a multi-project sbt build.

I installed sbt one-jar plugin, with the following in project/plugins.sbt

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases", new URL("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("com.github.retronym" % "sbt-onejar" % "0.8")
```

I can see sbt downloading the dependencies, but sbt somehow doesn't let me use it (i.e. execute `one-jar` in the sbt console), `one-jar` task isn't listed when I execute `tasks` command.

Any help is greaty appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add OneJar to your project settings.

```
settings = standardSettings ++ SbtOneJar.oneJarSettings
```

It is also described in the README on the github repo: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar#introduce-settings

Comment: where this should be added?